# Printf show the wrong number

Tags: c

```
char n[100];
int u[100];
int x[8];

scanf("%[^\n]",&n);
scanf("%d %d",&x,&u);


printf("%s\n",n); //print correct
printf("%d\n",x); //print not the exact number i input in scan
printf("%d\n",u);// print not the exact number i input in scan
```

if i input x and u for ex: 12345678 20
the output will print: random number

Comment: In the printf you should output `x[0]` and `u[0]`. What you actually wrote is undefined behaviour. Also the `scanf` should not have the `&` operator

Comment: Arrays for strings, ints, and ints. One of these is not like the others.

Answer (score 2):

For `%[^\n]`, `scanf` expects a pointer to a `char` (which is the first of enough `char` to receive the string), but `&n` is a pointer to an array of `char`. Change `scanf("%[^\n]",&n);` to `scanf("%[^\n]", n);`. Although `n` is an array of `char`, when used like this, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so a pointer to a `char` will be passed.

For `%d`, `scanf` expects a pointer to an `int`, but `&x` and `&u` are pointers to arrays of `int`. Change `int u[100];` to `int u;` and `int x[8];` to `int x;`. Then, in `scanf("%d %d",&x,&u);`, pointers to `int` will be passed.

In `printf("%s\n",n);`, for `%s`, `printf` expects a pointer to the first of several `char` to print, and `n` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so this is correct.

In `printf("%d\n",x);`, for `%d`, `printf` expects an `int`. Previously, when `x` was an array, this was passing a pointer to the first `int` in the array. Then `printf` may have been printing the pointer as if it were an `int`, but a variety of things can go wrong with this. With the corrected definition of `x` shown above, this will pass the value of `x` instead of a pointer, so it will be correct.

Similarly, `printf("%d\n",u);` will be correct once the definition of `u` is changed from an array to a single item.

Turn on warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them.